# Как работать с expo-router V2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Всем привет, я новичок в ReactNative и уже довольно давно не могу разобраться, как работает роутинг. Я заюзал шаблон с встроенной навигацией и TS. Насколько я понял, есть два пути - перейти к другому компоненту Link и router.replace. Но непонятно как можно передать объект JSON. И заюзать его там.

Я пробовал Link. Понятно, что там есть `params`, `path`, но объекты передать я не могу, так как через `useLocalSearchParams` выдает `[Object, Object]`.

Мой вопрос: Как при переходе с одного компонента передать объект в другой

Например,
есть `data`:

```
const data = {
      'Алматы': [
        {
          'title': '1',
          'phone': [
            "+7 (727) 3 200 200",
            "+7 701 981 81 54",
            "+7 747 094 46 91"
          ],
          'image': 'https://app.interteach.kz/img/mc1.png',
          'adress': 'пр. Назарбаева 275 Е, уг. ул. Хаджи Мукана',
          'hours': [
            {'Mon_Fri' : '08.00 – 20.00'},
            {'Sat_Sun' : '08.00 – 20.00'},
            {'Sun' : ''}
          ]
        },{
          'title': '2',
          'phone': [
            "+7 asd",
            "+7 701 981 dasdasda 54",
            "+7 747 094 46 91"
          ],
          'image': 'https://adsadasdpp.interteach.kz/img/mc1.png',
          'adress': 'пр. Назарбаева 275 Е, уг. ул. Хаджи Мукана',
          'hours': [
            {'Mon_Fri' : '08.00 – 20.00'},
            {'Sat_Sun' : '08.00 – 20.00'},
            {'Sun' : ''}
          ]
        },
      ],
  }
```

**В 1 компоненте я просто беру ключ Алматы и беру значение.length получаю количество клиник. Мне нужно далее кажду клинику передавать в другой компонент.**

**Как это работает сейчас:** *В 1 компоненте* :

```
{Object.entries(data).map(([city, clinics], index) => (
    <View key={index} style={styles.clinicItem}>
       <Link href="/components/clinics/ClinicItem" params={clinics}>
              <Text style={styles.clinicTitle}>{city}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.clinicNum}>
                {clinics.length}{clinicsWords(clinics.length)}
              </Text>
            
          </Link>
       
    </View>
  ))}
```

во втором: `const params = useLocalSearchParams<any>(); console.log(params)`

Вывод:

```
[Object, Object]
```

Comment: Покажите, что именно вы делаете и что не получается(нужен ваш код с комментариями)

Comment: @SwaD  извиняюсь, исправил